# Copy files excluding x,y,z causing error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I'm not well versed in shell scripting but I imagine this to be a painfully easy fix but its eluding me.

I need to copy the contents of a directory excluding a number of files. I have a command that works when I enter it into the terminal, but when its run in a shell script it fails with a syntax error or just doesn't work.

The command in question is:

```
cp -r path/to/!(dir1|dir2|dir3) destination
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's `ksh` syntax. `bash` only recognises that syntax when you enable its `extglob` option with:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

So, you need to add that line to the start of your script, or have it interpreted by `ksh` instead of `bash` or call your script with `env BASHOPTS=extglob your-script` (that latter one not recommended as it would enable the `extglob` option for every bash shell that your script spawns).

Possibly you have that option enabled in your `~/.bashrc` which is why it works at the prompt (`~/.bashrc` is only read by non-login interactive shells).